# How can I present an UIPopoverController from an UITableViewCell?

Tags: ipad, uipopovercontroller

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row == 5)
    {
        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
        [enginesPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:[tableView bounds] inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:[tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] inView:[self view] permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

Good Luck!